# Storing Var with the DropDown value, and then use the value for open a given html

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dropdown menu with the values pulled out from my sql Db.

after selecting the value, it is stored in a variable.

Lets say that i choose an option "ABC" and this is stored into the variable, i then want to use this var for opening the html file on my localhost named ABC.html

Baiscily the objectiv is redirect the user to the web page related to his choice.

here is my Script:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
function getOption() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("choosedOP");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>
        <title>ComboBox Ajax, PHP y MySQL</title>
        <script src="includes/js.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="getOp1();">

        <div id="op1"></div> <br />

        <div id="op2"></div> <br />

        <div id="op3"></div>
        <input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Click Me!">
    </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When  i click the submit button it retrieves the selected option. How can i make it to redirect to any html select by the user?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
   
function getOption() {
    obj = document.getElementById("choosedOP");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
}
function redirect(){
 obj = document.getElementById("choosedOP");
var href = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
window.location=href;
}
</script>
        <title>ComboBox Ajax, PHP y MySQL</title>
        <script src="includes/js.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input type="button" id="redirect" value="redirect" onclick="redirect()">
        <select id="choosedOP">
        <option>http://wiki.com</option>
        <option>https://www.wikipedia.org/</option>
        </select>
        <div id="op1"></div> <br />

        <div id="op2"></div> <br />

        <div id="op3"></div>
        <input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Click Me!">
    </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, but it gave some clues. Thanks

Comment: glad to hear you're somewhat on the right track...the key point here is the ***window.location*** piece of code  :D

Comment: I've spend the last weak tryng to figure out how to display the selected option. Today i made it. Now lets advance for more advanced stuff (lol)

Comment: please comment my answer to this post. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirect(){
 obj = document.getElementById("choosedoption");
var href = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
window.location.href = 'obj.php?=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

Does this make any sense?